# How to customize the project.properties in HTML5Boilerplate to publish the website?

Tags: javascript, html, html5boilerplate

I have made a website in VS2010 (in HTML and JavaScript)

Now I am using HTML5Boilerplate to publish my website.
Now to minify the javascript files I need to specify their path in a file that is under the build folder by name project.properties.

In that file their is the below structure in which you can specify the files that need to be minified.
dir.publish
dir.js
dir.js.libs
dir.js.mylibs
dir.css
dir.images

The problem is I have two folder in my website that contain .js file and I need to minify them all.

Now in project.properties I can specify the path of that folder by writing

dir.js = /AppSrc/direct/js/mylibs/grids
In the grid folder are my .js files.

but I have another folder that has the .js files.
So how can I specify two folder paths that contain .js files in project.properties.

If anyone has done this please let me know on how I can do this.

Comment: Someone please reply to this.

Answer (score 0):

You cant have two different parent folders for JS libs with the ant build script.